# Laravel Many to Many relationships are Throwing an SQL Error

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, relationship

When I make this call

```
  foreach ($phones->cases as $case) {            
  
  }
```

I am getting this error. Somehow it is changing the lk_case table name to l_k__case_id.

The end goal is that I'd like to be able to display a list of phones and their details in a blade template, and while looping that, display the phone cases that they have with the details of those as well.

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'phone_cases.l_k__case_id' in 'field list' 
(SQL: select `lk_case`.*, `phone_cases`.`phone_id` as `pivot_phone_id`, 
`phone_cases`.`l_k__case_id` as `pivot_l_k__case_id` from `lk_case` 
inner join `phone_cases` on `lk_case`.`id` = `phone_cases`.`l_k__case_id` 
where `phone_cases`.`phone_id` in (11063))
```

These are the three models.
Phone
PhoneCase
LK_Case

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Phone extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'phone';

    public $primaryKey = 'id';

    protected $fillable = [
        'title',
        ]; 

    public function cases(){

        return $this->belongsToMany(LK_Case::class,'phone_cases');  
        
    }

}



namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class PhoneCase extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $primaryKey = ['phone_id', 'case_id'];
    public $incrementing = false;
    protected $fillable = ['phone_id','case_id'];  
}

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class LK_Case extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'lk_case';

    public $primaryKey = 'id';

    protected $fillable = [
        'id','phone_case_name'
    ];

    public function phones()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Phone::class, 'phone_cases'); 
    }
    
}
```

Comment: You should show also tables structure (ex. migrations) and what query is under $phones.

Comment: That error is happening because you are not following convention... The documentation clearly states that it will add `_id` to the class name as a default relation column, so `LK_Case` will be `l_k__case`, why double underscore ? Because you wrote `LK_Case` when it should have been `Lkcase` or `LkCase`.

Comment: Gotcha, makes sense thanks will check that out.  It was an existing database.   Can I just change the class name all across the code, and in the model, without hurting anything?